# What’s the Name of this OnePager Feature?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I hope this is the right place for this question, but I found no other suitable place for it. (If not...sorry!)

How do you call this technique when you have a OnePager theme with a number of sections after the start section, every section fills 100% width and 100% height and one small movement of the mouse wheel slides the content fluently to the next (or previous) section, which then fills the screen completely? (Desktop and Mobile).

I have tried some of the themes that were shown to me when searching "one page" on the WP themes page, but they didn't have this feature.

Which could be a free theme that uses this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try this link - [fullPage](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: @Bhautik: Very Good, thanks. How is this technique called?